# Tags semânticas para citação e autor

Tags: html, html5, html-tags, semântica

Estou fazendo uma *landing page* como *challenge* do Frontend Mentor e gostaria de saber quais as melhores *tags* semânticas para fazer esse bloco abaixo. Utilizei o `<blockquote>` para a citação, porém não sei qual tag usar para o autor da frase.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Uma pergunta importante que não foi comentado: o que significa esse bloco? Seriam depoimentos de clientes? Comentários em uma publicação? Resposta a um questionário?

Comment: Como é algo fictício não sei dizer exatamente o que seria, em minha interpretação imaginei que fossem apenas relatos de pessoas que trabalham em empresas imaginárias que utilizam o serviço da Fylo. Assim como aqueles sites que colocam os relatos das pessoas que fizeram uma avaliação no Facebook.

Comment: Então discordo com uso de `<blockquote>`, pois você não estaria citando uma fonte externa. Está apenas apresentando depoimentos e isso não é uma citação.

Comment: @Alexandre Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou me baseando [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29724679/221800) no SO.

```html
<blockquote>"Money is the real cause of poverty,"
    <footer>
        <cite id="baseref">The Ragged-Trousered Philanthropists, page 89.</cite>
    </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Isto está de acordo com o [exemplo da especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element). Mas não tem nada na específica que só assim é certo.

E que antes se fazia assim, o que particularmente achei mais bonito:

```html
<figure>
    <blockquote>
        "This is what I think"
    </blockquote>
    <footer>
        — <cite class="author">My Name</cite>, <cite class="company">My Company</cite>
    </footer>
</figure>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Figure.html).

Tem uma outra resposta que usou esta forma:

```html
<blockquote cite="http://a.uri.com/">
    <p>This is a really insightful sentence.</p>
    <cite>Darko Z</cite>
</blockquote>
```

E nela cita que em HTML5 a citação não deve usar o nome do autor, então é um pouco confuso.

A [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite) que é meio que uma documentação "oficial" que as pessoas usam dá este exemplo:

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.</p>
    <footer>
        First sentence in <cite><a href="http://www.george-orwell.org/1984/0.html"><i>Nineteen Eighty-Four</i></a></cite> by George Orwell (Part 1, Chapter 1).
    </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Mas já vi coisas erradas na MDN.

Um trecho importante da específica:

> User agents may allow users to follow such citation links, but they are primarily intended for private use (e.g: by server-side scripts collecting statistics about a site's edits), not for readers

Está dizendo que o uso disto não é para o leitor e sim para algo interno, privado, para uso de ferramentas.

Seu uso parece mais interessante para os indexadores que podem usá-lo como quiserem, não tem um padrão estabelecido.

Tem outra perguntas que tem [respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2205159/221800), mas não achei elas tão fundamentas.

Procurei e não achei um jeito certo de fazer, tem a ver com gosto, principalmente se a citação não envolve um aspecto científico, mas é bom usar o `cite` de uma forma ou outra para dar semântica e pelo menos os buscadores indexarem de forma adequada. Provavelmente ajudará na acessibilidade, e algumas ferramentas pode ter seu trabalho melhor.

Obviamente o visual é algo que você dará com CSS e outras formas do HTML que nada tem a ver com a citação em si.

Comment: Fantástico já me trouxe uma luz muito grande, reparei que ainda não há um certo consenso e dando uma olhada em outras fontes  percebi esse mesmo problema, mas esses seus exemplos me pareceram muito bons, verei o que melhor se enquadra para a minha intenção. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Numa `blockquote` podes usar tag `footer` para mencionar a origem da mesma, exemplo:

```html
<blockquote cite="http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000672/quotes">
<p>You know the golden rule, don’t you boy? Those who have the gold make the rules.</p>
<footer>— <a href="http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000672/quotes">Crazy hunch-backed old guy in Aladdin</a></footer>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Interessante, parece-me que tem mais haver com o que eu preciso. Muito obrigado